# How to get the build output in a specific target directory using Visual Studio (maybe MsBuild)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, msbuild

Compiling a class library with a .NET project with a project file holding

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
      <OutputPath>C:\aaa</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

results in the assemblies in

```
   c:\aaa\net48
```

I need them in straight

```
   c:\aaa
```

What is the most pragmatic way to achieve that?

I tried to set configuration to the empty value with

```
<Configuration></Configuration>
```

but that has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `OutDir` property to overwrite the path.

Use this:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'"> 
    <OutDir>C:\aaa\</OutDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```